# FluxCD image not updated on helm release

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, fluxcd

I started with FluxCD, and I'm looking to update my helm releases with each new image that was pushed into docker registry. So far I have my policies and `imageautomation` in place - which are working fine, I can see that git repo is updated with the latest docker tag. Now the problem is although `helmrelease` kustomization file is updated in git with new tags, it doesn't applies changes to the `helmrelease` in cluster. I would appreciate any hint on what's miss configured.
Bellow you can see my relevant for the context configuration:

```
# kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: tor
resources:
  - ./../application/stat
  - ./fluxkustomize.yaml

#fluxkustomize.yaml
---
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: stat
  namespace: tor
spec:
  interval: 1m0s
  prune: false
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: gitops
    namespace: tor
  images:
    - name: ecr/tor
      newName: ecr/tor # {"$imagepolicy": "tor:stat:name"}
      # based on policy, latest tag was updated in git accordingly
      newTag: 1.3.4 # {"$imagepolicy": "tor:stat:tag"}

# ../application/stat/helmrelease.yaml
---
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: stat
spec:
  values:
    api:
      image:
        repository: ecr/tor
    image:
      tag: 1.3.0
  interval: 1m0s
  releaseName: stat
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: ./helm/stat
      interval: 1m0s
      valuesFile: ./helm/stat/values.yaml
      sourceRef:
        kind: GitRepository
        name: stat
        namespace: tor
```

Answer (score -1):

So the problem here was that the path that I was editing in helmrelease was changed and I was aiming to alter non-existing image values.